# Prove that the set, $C$, of continuous functions is not a subspace of the differentiable functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I cannot for the life of me figure out this problem:

Prove that the set, $C$, of continuous functions on the interval $(-1, 1)$ is not a vector subspace of the set, $D$, of differentiable functions on that interval.

Maybe I'm completely making this up, but I thought all differentiable functions were continuous.

How do I attack this problem?

The question is titled: **Looking for a way to pass the time?**

Comment: All differentiable functions are continuous, but not all continuous functions are differentiable. There are easy examples.

Comment: You just need to find one continuous function on $(-1,1)$ that is not differentiable on $(-1,1)$. Check out the Weierstrauss function

Comment: @graydad: That’s working awfully hard for an example. What about the familiar function whose graph is a $\lor$, more or less?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No questions there that that is a much easier example. My comment was biased, as I am very intrigued by the properties of the Weierstrauss function

Comment: @graydad@BrianM.Scott: Bottom line:The fact it's not closed under the set of all continuous maps-i.e. the fact there's at least one continuous map which is not differentiable at all points of the domain-is sufficient to prove the falsity of the statement.

Comment: What do you mean, "The question is titled: Looking for a way to pass the time?"?

Comment: My teacher wrote "Looking for a way to pass the time" above the question. I couldn't tell if this was a hint, or if it literally meant, "If you are bored and want another problem, try this one."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick your favorite function that is continuous on $(-1,1)$, but not differentiable at *some* point in $(-1,1)$, like $f(x)=|x|$ or $g(x)=x^{2/3}$ (neither is differentiable at $x=0$).

The upshot here is that if $X$ is not a **subset** of $Y$, then $X$ cannot be a **subspace** of $Y$.